# Data Driven Pages: Printing issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I am creating some maps for bird species records, an example for “A” and “B” birds is shown below. I managed to use Data Driven Pages to create a map for each species set of records that show species distribution and breeding status.  So far the created maps are fine, however, I have a problem in printing. The DDP keeps repeating printing species map which depends on number of each species records in the index layer. I just want to print one map per species.

[image]

I am using ArcMap 10.3

Comment: You don't mention what software you are using?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.3

Comment: I don't use ArcGis but have used DDP tools in other software so this may apply here. DDP will likely be creating a page for *each* record in your source table. If you only want one page per species then you may need to create a second table containing one record per bird species and the center point of the map location for that species. Perhaps someone with more experience in DDP on ArcGis can confirm but that would be my first guess and gives you something to have a go at while waiting for a better answer.

Comment: @T_Bacon +1 That's the way it works in ArcGIS as well - may be worth posting that as an answer

Comment: Thanks T_Bacon. In order to create a map that shows species distribution, I need to have all records per each species to be mapped together in one map.   Also, I need to consider the breeding status for each record. I created these maps but the tricky bit is in printing. May be the way to go is using arcpy.mapping script to export selected Data Driven Pages but this will require me to insert a new field and create a unique name for each record which seems very difficult task. I wonder if there is any script that automatically avoid repeating printing  pages with the same name?!

Comment: @T_Bacon's comment is correct. In DDP, you get 1 map per record in whatever field you use as your "index" field. So it's working the way it's supposed to.

Comment: I'd suggest going through a few tutorials on DDP, what you want to do is much simpler than you're making it. You just need to create a new polygon layer to use as your index layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use ArcGis but have used DDP tools in other software so this may apply here. DDP will likely be creating a page for *each* record in your source table. If you only want one page per species then you may need to create a second table containing one record per bird species and the center point of the map location for that species. This doesn't mean you can't include your original table of data, only that the DDP process will use your new table with unique species as the source for creating each page. Basically you are just using this table to tell DDP how many pages you want, where you want each page to be centred and possibly as a source for other data, e.g. species name in your map layout, though this depends on how this specific DDP tool works.